# backup And restore in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server - Database ‘Database’ does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358148/sql-server-database-database-does-not-exist-make-sure-that-the-name-is-ente)

I wrote this code, but the database does not recognize the backup? Kindly guide

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Resources\dbcn.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string MasterPath = "c://";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                //BACKUP DATABASE نام بانک اطلاعاتی TO DISK = 'مسیر پشتیبان گیری بانک اطلاعاتی'
                string query = "BACKUP DATABASE dbcn TO DISK = '" + MasterPath + @"\BackupLibrary" + "\\dbcn.mdf" + "'";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
            catch(System.Exception EX)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);

            }
```

Error;

```
Database 'dbcn' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: I have to ask. When you connect to the `dbcn.mdf` database file with SQL Server Management Studio, can you verify that a database by the name `dbcn` exists? There's no guarantee that it does, just because the mdf is so named. What databases are present in that file?

Answer (score 0):

It may be more than you need for this project, but in the future you may want to investigate SQL Management Objects(SMO). It gives you the ability to perform SQL Server maintenance tasks in managed code (for example c#).

I believe it is part of the SQL Server SDK. You will need to add the following references to your project:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
```

I was able to find these assemblies in the following location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\

```
string ServerName = "server";
string DatabaseName = database;
string UserId = userId;
string Password = password;
ServerConnection serverConnection;

private Server _server;
public Server Server
{
    get
    {
        if (_server == null)
        {
            Connect();
        }
        return _server;
    }
}

string connectionString 
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};UID={2};Password={3}", ServerName, DatabaseName, UserId, Password);
    }
}

public void Connect()
{
    _serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
    _serverConnection.LoginSecure = false;
    _serverConnection.Login = UserId;
    _serverConnection.Password = Password;

    _server = new Server(_serverConnection);
}

public void BackupDatabase()
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        ServerConnection svCon = new ServerConnection(cn);
        Server svr = new Server(svCon);
        cn.Open();
        cn.ChangeDatabase("master");

        string testFolder = @"C:\temp";
        string databaseName = _databaseName;
        Backup backup = new Backup();
        backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        backup.Database = databaseName;
        backup.Incremental = false;
        backup.Initialize = true;
        backup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.bak", testFolder, databaseName);
        BackupDeviceItem backupItemDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fileName, DeviceType.File);
        backup.Devices.Add(backupItemDevice);
        backup.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
        //backup.PercentComplete += backup_PercentComplete;
        //backup.Complete += backup_Complete;

        backup.SqlBackup(svr);
        if (!VerifyBackup(svr))
        {
            //throw new Exception("Backup could not be verified.");
        }
        svr = null;
        cn.Close();
    }
}

public bool VerifyBackup(Server svr)
{
    string testFolder = @"C:\temp";
    string databaseName = _databaseName;
    Restore restore = new Restore();
    restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.bak", testFolder, databaseName);
    BackupDeviceItem backupItemDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fileName, DeviceType.File);
    restore.Devices.AddDevice(fileName, DeviceType.File);
    restore.Database = databaseName;
    restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
    //restore.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(ProgressEventHandler);

    bool verified = restore.SqlVerify(svr);
    return verified;
}

public void RestoreDatabase()
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        ServerConnection svCon = new ServerConnection(cn);
        Server svr = new Server(svCon);
        cn.Open();
        cn.ChangeDatabase("master");

        string testFolder = @"C:\temp";
        string databaseName = _databaseName;
        Restore restore = new Restore();
        restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.bak", testFolder, databaseName);
        BackupDeviceItem backupItemDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fileName, DeviceType.File);
        restore.Devices.AddDevice(fileName, DeviceType.File);
        restore.Database = databaseName;
        restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
        restore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10;
        //restore.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(ProgressEventHandler);
        svr.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);

        restore.SqlRestore(svr);
        svr = null;
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```